# WPF Converter can't access base property

Tags: c#, wpf, converters

Im trying to achive something like here [WPF DataGrid Grouping with sums and other fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24618966/wpf-datagrid-grouping-with-sums-and-other-fields?answertab=votes#tab-top) to sum up 'quantity' property from items in a group. But it throws exception in foreach loop that it cant convert 'items' to my Type ('OrderItem' of which i thought items should be...) 
C#

```
 public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {

        if (value is ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Object>)
        {
            var items = ((ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Object>) value);
            Decimal total = 0;
            foreach (OrderItem gi in items )
            {
                total += gi.quantity;
            }
            return total.ToString();

        }
        return "0";
    }
```

XAML

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                        <Expander>
                                            <Expander.Header>
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Margin="5"/>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="Count" Margin="5" />
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Items, Converter={StaticResource additionConverter}}" Margin="5"/>
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </Expander.Header>
                                            <ItemsPresenter />
                                        </Expander>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
```

and resource

```
<local:AdditionConverter x:Key="additionConverter" />
```

how to get access to the base element of 'value'? I puted a breakpoint and it is there.
Sorry if i messed up something, i'm new to WPF.

Comment: What is the type of item which it is showing if not OrderItem ?

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'MS.Internal.Data.CollectionViewGroupInternal' to 'Plan_Produkcji_Beta.OrderItem'

Comment: My guess is it would be something to do with your binding, in that i am thinking that your binding to a property of a WPF control rather than directly to the data. What can you provide the xaml for the item using the Converter?

Comment: I have posted it in my question

Comment: Is `Items` part of the OrderItem type? I suspect you want to bind to the collection of items, but you have the wrong DataContext in the TextBlock binding for `Items`.

Comment: no its not. probably thats the point but i have no idea how to change it. All i want is to sum up a quantity property of items in group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this :

```
   foreach (OrderItem gi in items )
        {
            total += gi.quantity;
        }
```

with :

```
   foreach (CollectionViewGroup group in items)
     {
        foreach(OrderItem item in group.Items)
        {
           total += item.quantity;
        } 
     }
```

and tell if this solves your problem.

Comment: @kasperro Download ILSpy now.